# Outlook SPO EMail Attachment Permission Error With ActiveX

Tags: javascript, email, outlook, activex, email-attachments

Since an recently upcoming Outlook 2016 update, we got a huge deal breaker issue with attachments from SharePoint Online attached at a mail item.

Our software solution opens an Outlook-Mail-Element with attachments from Sharepoint-Online (direct links) by the ActiveX interface.

That scenario worked always well till one of the last updates. 
Now, the attachment is still displayed, but Outlook notifies that there is no permission to download the file due to permission conflicts (though nothing changed by us or customer). If you click on the the attachment by yourself, you can force the file to download and everthing works fine.

If I set the file from Sharepoint with the direct link manually as attachment (add File dialog) everything works fine as well as the behaviour before the update came up. Actually the permission to the file is there.

File looks like like the following with the error as I described:

[image]

Sorry I got the German version of Outlook =) 
The text below the file name in English: Error by download file..

[image]

Message: You don't have the required permissions to download this file (Try again, Cancel) 
By clicking "Try again" everything works fine.

Just a small dump of my code:

```
OL = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
mailitem = OL.CreateItem(0);
mailitem.Attachments.Add(url);
```